# Suddenly, all links in #content div are not clickable, but I don't see any z-index bug?

Tags: css, bug

Following a bunch of seemingly harmless plugin updates, I suddenly have a weird bug.  All of the links in my #content section are now unclickable, although the links in my sidebar, header, footer, etc. remain all fine.  Usually this would imply a CSS z-index bug is overlaying the #content area somehow, but I hadn't changed any CSS.

Here's an example: https://www.reclaimtherecords.org/faq/

Note how the links in the main article are unclickable, but the sidebar links to other pages are fine?

I'm using a slightly-modified child theme, of the Themify Landing theme.

I'm stumped -- help!

Comment: Links are clickable for me on that page on Windows 7 with Chrome.

Comment: On a Mac running OSX El Capitan 10.11.4, they're not clickable in the #content area on a Mac using Chrome 50.0.2661.86 (64-bit), nor on Firefox 44.02.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's easy. You have the following CSS rule:

```
a.themify_lightbox, 
.module-image a, 
.module-gallery a, 
.gallery-icon, 
.themify_lightboxed_images .post a, 
.themify_lightboxed_images .type-page a, 
.themify_lightboxed_images .type-highlight a, 
.themify_lightboxed_images .type-slider a {

    pointer-events: none;  
    cursor: default;
}
```

This rule applies because `body` has a class `themify_lightboxed_images`.

`pointer-events: none;` is the last thing you want on your links. This basically means that the element doesn't exist to cursors and you can click right through it..

---

If you want to enforce your own rules without changing any theme's styles or add CSS classes to all your links, add the following CSS rule:

```
a {
   pointer-events: auto !important;  
   cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

You should generally avoid `!important` but it will do as a temporary fix. It will overwrite all your links. I suggest to find a better solution as soon as possible.

Just a tip: this is purely a CSS question and should be asked in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/). I hope you know better next time.

Comment: THANK YOU!  My parent theme, Themify Landing, seems to have been the culprit, by adding the themify_lightbox class to everything indiscriminately.